# One Interstitial ad through whole App

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, admob, interstitial

I have an activity with around four fragments and these fragments has child fragments. I have a static counter with static InterstitialAd in The Mainactivity that is called through fragments, however it leads to memory leak. Is there a better practise?

Inside main

```
static int clicksCount,newsCount;
private static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public static void interstitalAd() {
    clicksCount++;
    if (clicksCount % 3 == 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I need to call it from fragments

```
MainActivity.interstitalAd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not necessary or wise to story the `InterstitialAd` itself as a static member, since it will then retain the context it was created with indefinitely.

Better to do:

```
static int clicksCount,newsCount;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public void interstitalAd() {
    clicksCount++;
    if (clicksCount % 3 == 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `Fragment`:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
mainActivity.interstitialAd();
```

Comment: Well I was thinking of creating a singelton class, which would be a better practise?

Comment: Even if the `Activity` is intended to be a singleton, it will still have an instance and can have instance members.

Comment: well I will give your solution a try as I have a static drawer that I had to lock inside one of the fragments which could possible lead to a leak. Could work for both. I will update you as Im done :)